# jQuery cycle - start (from the beginning) on hover, stop on hoverout

Tags: jquery-cycle

I have a list of thumbnail items that contain a hidden popup container that only shows when I hover over them. That container contains a `<ul>` who's `<li>`s act as the slides.

What I am trying to achieve is to start the slideshow from the beginning each time the user hovers over a thumbnail, and stop it when the user hovers out.

It works fine for a while but after multiple hovers it tends to break, as if 2 slideshow timers are accessing the same list causing various glitches like images flashing out of order and such.

I tried cycle('stop') on hoverout but then when the slideshow restarts, it stops on the second slide.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I achieved it by combining cycle('pause') and

```
$('.item-list ul li',this).each(function(){$(this).removeAttr('style');});
```

using removeAttr removes all the inline styles jquery.cycle added thus leaving the list clean and refresh to re-set the cycle on the next mouseover.